# Should we allow "useless" tags and what are "useless" tags for Apple.SE?

Tags: discussion, tags

What is the list of tags we should not allow? Much like how on most other SE sites tags like `homework`, `subjective`, etc. have been disallowed. It doesn't stop anybody from *asking* homework-related or subjective questions but at least we don't actually roll out the red carpet.

For more info check out: [Should we permanently remove the [subjective] tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51627/should-we-permanently-remove-the-subjective-tag) on Meta.SO.

Comment: I'm going to lock this. With two questions, it got the discussion started in 2010 but isn't answerable or continuing the discussion today.

Answer (score 7):

I think that if we have an `[apple]` tag, it will be used in a way that doesn't add any value.  Maybe we can use `[apple inc]` for questions related to the company.

Comment: Yes, my thoughts exactly when I noticed someone had retagged [this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/715/what-was-the-very-first-apple-product) with [apple]. 
[apple-inc] might indeed be better as it makes it clearer it's about the *company*. If we do keep the [apple] tag, it will certainly be used in completely superfluous ways (like [programming] on Stack Overflow).

Answer (score 6):

At first I believed they'd add clutter but using `[mac]` for any Mac based questions, `[iphone]` for iPhone based questions, etc. will help users categorize the type of Apple question. My initial impressions was wrong but I still believe there will be a list of tags that should not be allowed. The ones I first gave are not them.

Comment: Can you edit the question & title then? Sounds like a good idea.

Comment: @Josh K: Toned down the suck!

Comment: +agreed.  I think [apple] is definitely useless as it's the basic premise of the site.  [mac], [osx], [iphone], etc, are very usefull.

Answer (score 4):

[Mac] strikes me as the single most superfluous tag. [OSX] while seemingly useless at a glance, is actually fairly useful for categorizing general system software questions that aren't specific to one version or another. Similarly, [Apple] makes perfect sense as a tag for questions about Apple, The Company, rather than Apple, The Subject - But if folks would rather that tag be [Apple, Inc.], I don't think that's a problem either.

Questions about Mac Hardware, should, for clarity, probably be tagged with the particular product line (i.e. [iMac], [PowerBook], [Mac Mini]), or category ([Notebook], [Desktop]). I can really only count on one hand the sort of questions that could generally be applied to all Macs across that sort of categorization scheme that would actually benefit from a tag of [Mac] and not something else entirely.

Comment: [Is it OSX or OS X?](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/q/609/8546)

Answer (score 2):

Why should we not allow `[mac]` or `[apple]` tags?

Is there a distinct clutter benefit to not allowing them?

Some tags that I think we should not allow:

- `[linux]`
- `[windows]`

Okay, just a joke. I can't think of any tags that *shouldn't* be allowed, except for standard subjective questions, questions that are clearly argumentative (`windows-vs-mac`?) or spiteful (`i-can't-google`).

Comment: As was proposed in the other question on the subject, [apple] as a tag makes a great deal of sense for questions about the company. [osx] for general OS questions seems fine as well. [mac] however, feels very superfluous to me.

Comment: @Less: Then submit and answer indicating that. I'm starting to feel the same way however. :)

Comment: I didn't have the rep to before!